# I'm getting 403 Fobidden Error after successfully deploying my laravel app using Deployer

Tags: laravel, php-deployer

I successfully deployed my laravel app to app.example.com using deployer on windows (my local pc I mean), the app is deployed to a VPS Server running on Linux with a LEMP Stack configuration. There were no errors in deployment as shown in the image below; however when I attempt to access app.example.com I get a 403 Error. How do I resolve this? Any help?

[Snapshot of Successful Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfefv.png)

[Snapshot of Forbidden Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd2Ke.png)

Comment: you maybe need to add the host dns resolution in your local installation. file host : `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` in a new line add `127.0.0.1 api.example.com`

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, I'm working with a Widows OS but the Server Runs on Linux.

Comment: I already have a dns A Record for app.example.com on Cloudflare.